# Проблема с подгрузкой данных

Tags: objective-c

Подскажите пожалуйста.
При такой форме записи:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView

CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;
CGRect bounds = scrollView.bounds;
CGSize size = scrollView.contentSize;
UIEdgeInsets inset = scrollView.contentInset;
float y = offset.y + bounds.size.height - inset.bottom;
float h = size.height;
float reload_distance = 800;
if(y > h - reload_distance && loadData == NO && new == NO) {
    NSLog(@"load more rows");
    [APIDownload downloadWithURL:MyWebString delegate:self];
}
```

Проблема в том, что метод [APIDownload downloadWithURL:MyWebString delegate:self]; не вызывается пока скрол не остановиться, подскажите как исправить.

Comment: а лог выдает? условие проходит? какие значения у переменных в условии перед проверкой?

Comment: Да, проверку проходит, в логе пишет:
NSLog(@"load more rows");
но закачка не начинается.

Comment: Попробуйте выделить эту функцию в отдельный метод. У меня подобное было, как раз с делегатными методами.

Comment: К сожалению как только не пробовал, и в другую функцию и селекторы делал. Что-то никак.

Comment: Не увидел про анимацию :) ... Пока отрабатывает "анимация" обработака Приложения "останавливается", а тем более обращение к методам требующим внешнего взаимодействия.

Вывод:
1. Меняете архитектуру, создаете "невидимый" кеш, который грузится ДО анимации. Пользуетесь им.
2. Включаете "потоки" и грузите отдельным потоком.

Comment: Метод сделал в другом потоке:
- (void)APIDownload:(APIDownload*)request {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
... code ...
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            });
});
}
Если делать кэш, то это закачивать все данные, а их много, если закачивать близжайшее к примеру на 100 ячеек, то после прокрутки 100 ячеек все равно возвращаюсь к этой же проблеме

Answer (score 1):

Странное решение задачи. [Погуглите как это делают другие](http://bit.ly/1jsxwII)
А что косается Вашего вопроса. То как Вы узнаете что метод не вызывается? Может просто делегаты не вызываются? И во-вторых, проверьте потоки.